# Make Proofreader a silver badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, review-badges

So, recently, the [Reviewer bronze badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing) was introduced, and, shortly thereafter, [made a silver badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing/111329#111329):

> Originally I thought a bronze makes sense here. But in retrospect I do not. [...]
>
> Introducing a bronze badge here is **odd**. Traditionally bronze badges are "welcome to the system" badges.

This made me think of another bronze badge introduced a few months back: **Proofreader**. It is also odd as a bronze badge because:

- It is certainly not a "welcome" badge, as you need to be fairly established already to have a shot at it (5k+ to access the edit queue).
- Reviewing 100 suggestions is not that easy a task, especially when compared to other bronze tasks, like "voting on a post" or "making an edit".

If we take the decision-making part out of the equation, it'd still involve *finding* 100 suggestions to vote on, and then reviewing them before someone else does. Maybe I'm just on the [wrong site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) for this sort of thing, but having *any* suggested edits in the queue is rather uncommon. Personally, 100 took me about 3 months (and one guy who was *really* keen on editing tag wikis).

This might be less of a problem on SO, what with requiring 2-3 votes and having an insane amount of activity, but still.

**TL;DR** Proofreader should be made a silver badge, maybe with raised requirements.

Comment: If you're going to include a `tl;dr` block, you should probably not put it at the bottom, where anyone who thinks your post is "too long" will, uh, "didn't read" to.

Comment: @PopularDemand The TL;DR block is there for who read all the post and are still wondering, "What is this post about?" `:-)`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, once having acquired the 5k reputation, it is extremely easy to get the Proofreader badge. By then, you do not have to search for edit suggestions; simply find them by visiting *http://[site].com/review/*.

Besides that, when considering "welcome to the system" the only argument for badges being bronze, the question targets other badges as well, e.g. every bronze Tag badge and Quorum. Change them too?

I am not sure this badge should become silver.

Comment: I know. Finding as in, checking the edit queue and actually being lucky enough to find a suggested edit there. On SO, getting this badge is probably only limited by how fast you can hit the approve button, but I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: To address the edits: I'd say Quorum *is* a welcome badge ("made a contribution to meta"). As for tag badges, well, they're a different beast. There's 3 tiers, and I suppose they have to start *somewhere*.

Comment: Maybe the threshold for less popular sites should be lowered then.

Comment: @NGLN, Similar ideas of scaling badge requirements has [been](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96408/is-it-possible-to-adjust-the-requirements-for-badges-in-an-se-site-according-to) [raised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69689/shouldnt-the-badge-requirements-scale) [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84842/request-reduce-tag-badge-requirements-for-a-rare-tag). Personally, I think scaling the badge requirements will just get problematic as the site grows.

Answer (score 5):

I think that on every site other than on SO, this is the hardest bronze badge to get (other than precognitive), by a lot. There are simply not that many suggested edits that just hang around in the queue. On SU and SF, it is the bronze badge with the lowest number of people that have attained it. As such, would be nice if it was a silver.