# Are there any Statistics of before/after the new Beta Review system

Tags: discussion, review, statistics, low-quality-posts

So I've been watching the numbers for the low quality posts in the review system and I've been noticing a distinct trend.

They seem to be going down. *(As of writing this the count is at 43.2K)*

I was just wondering on the the numbers before and if the trend was going up? Personally I think the system is great and encourages me to look more at posts but I think the system is only a success if the numbers show it is.

So what do the statistics say?

**EDIT:** just to be specific I was mostly intrigued by this number(below)

[image: Screen capture of the current number for the low quality posts queue]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about total low-quality posts, but I *can* tell you that, before the new review system was put into place, the suggested edits queue was getting full on a regular basis (which requires 200 unreviewed entries, I believe).

Since the new review system was put into place, this queue is regularly staying in the low double-digits or less.  As I write this, there are currently three posts in the suggested edits queue.

Comment: On Stack Overflow? Or Meta?

Comment: On Stack Overflow.  The suggested edits queue is essentially irrelevant on Meta.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the feeling the quality of suggested edit review has not gone up. (<-- read: gone down I think, but I can't prove it)

Comment: @Bart: Unfortunately, [I think you're right.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142887/102937)

Comment: I'm not sure what the original number was but I remember the queue being 46K a day or so ago.