# Anonymous user suggested edit spam

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, anonymous

There seems to be an issue going around at the moment, where I've seen a number of edits to post that are complete vandalism. Presumably, these get filtered out by diligent users who notice that there is something wrong with the edit, but it would be nice to reduce the work load. What can we do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Nothing (15 chars)

Comment: Just reject and move on? The system works, if you notice them.

Comment: Are you certain you are not looking at Suggested Edit audits? And the system works; the edits are being reviewed and rejected. Too many rejections for a given user and they are blocked from suggesting more edits for a week.

Comment: We can increase the number of diligent users who will notice by making suggested edits available in review queues. We're already doing that, actually, and so far the system seems to be working.

Comment: Do you have an example of such obvious vandalism? Have you looked at them back to see if any of them got accept votes?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I posted one example in my answer. I've seen at least once that the edit was accepted by a particularly clever example of spam, but it's been a while... But mostly, this is just to make a spammer's life harder, and the "police"'s work easier.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I believe such examples are belong to the question, as they are not bound to a specific solution

Comment: [Presumably](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/493364) ;-) (Okay, old example.)

Comment: Related, if you're seeing a single account suggesting the edits: [Auto rollback any edits made by a spammer when his account get nuked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132732/auto-rollback-any-edits-made-by-a-spammer-when-his-account-get-nuked).

Comment: @Arjan the real WTF is two 20k robo-reviewing. One of them has exactly 1000 reviews, and both of them have extremely low rejection ratio

Comment: @Arjan also note the number of reviews needed has been increased to 3 since then. Also, when were audits introduced?

Comment: http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=20021103